# Complex state management with prevState (React 17 / Create React App 4.0)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I haven't worked with a purely state-based project in some time, this is a personal for-fun thing of mine (we use a Redux-like and persistence at work, so global state access is a lot more prop-driven). I'm putting nested ternaries into a setState hook (`setAvailableCharacters`) and I'm not a fan? Is there a better way I could be doing this?

```
  function levelCharacterUp(forceLevel = false) {
    setAvailableCharacters(prevState => (
        merge({}, availableCharacters, {
          [selectedClassKey]: {
            level: forceLevel ? forceLevel : prevState[selectedClassKey].level + 1 <= MAX_CHARACTER_LEVEL ? prevState[selectedClassKey].level + 1 : MAX_CHARACTER_LEVEL
          }
        })
      )
    );
  }
```

It doesn't seem that there's a cleaner way of doing this while also respecting the `prevState` chaining into the new state.

Trying to keep this purely a functional component, too.

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
  function levelCharacterUp(forceLevel = false) {
setAvailableCharacters(prevState => (
    merge({}, availableCharacters, {
      [selectedClassKey]: {
        level: forceLevel ? forceLevel : Math.min(prevState[selectedClassKey].level + 1, MAX_CHARACTER_LEVEL)
      }
    })
  )
);


 }
```